# neoauth is not installed with pip install of py2neo

Tags: python, neo4j, py2neo

Pip installing py2neo doesn't appear to install neoauth.

```
$ pip install py2neo
Requirement already satisfied: py2neo in ./venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages
$ neoauth
-bash: neoauth: command not found
```

Why is neoauth not installed? Is it installed but not in my path?
I can't find a reference to the word "neoauth" when I search for it in the site-package folder.

I ask because I'm having authentication problems and most of the answers online ask for the user to set the password using neoauth.

Comment: what are your auth problems ? do share code and error

Comment: Okay, let me put that in a different question though. For this one, I'm just trying to figure out why pip installing py2neo doesn't also install the command line utility.